# mongo db and rails id issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongomapper, spine.js

I'm working with a js framework called spine.
The framework can do all crud operations through REST api(like backbone). 
When I get a create request to my controller, I get a model data that has an id field from client side, I know that I'm in a create request so I should create a new record but mongo think this record already exists(because of the id field) and invokes update instead of insert.
Is there a way to solve this issue? I want client side to create this temporal id's but when calls server side create this id should be ignored.

some code:

```
#in my_controller
def create
  @model= Model.new(params[:modelData]) #model data is name=>"x", _id=>"c-0"
  @model.save
```

when save is called mongo do update, so next create will override this record.

Comment: do you use client generated id as '_id' in mongodb?

Comment: I don't know what's client generated id

Comment: Can you post some code to demonstrate the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had no choice but deleting the id field from the model I got from the client.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I understand your question, but I think you want this:

```
@model = Model.find_or_initialize_by_id(params[:modelData][:_id])
@model.update_attributes(params[:modelData])
```